# Full coverage path planner

Tags: navigation, mapping, path, global-planner, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a differential robot, with a laser Hokuyo, and I want my robot to cover the whole part of a map.
I saw that there is some algorithms but I can't find a code. So have someone already implement such algorithms?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185718/full-coverage-path-planner/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-10**:
Is it really hopeless?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-03-27**:
hey @Moda im trying to work on the same algorithm, been really hard getting around it. have you had any progress/luck since the time u asked ur question here? Thanks!

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-15**:
Similar to http://answers.ros.org/question/174998/path-planning-for-sensortool-coverage/ (and a few others listed there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have a map already or do you want to build a complete map of your environment? In the latter case, you could try the exploration module from: http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d

It completely explores an unknown environment and builds a map using 2D Laser-Scanner.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-17**:
I already have the map. What I want is that the robot cover the complete map, it must go in every free space of the map.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2014-07-17**:
Then you have to somehow define, which area of the map is covered when the robot moves within the map. But I don't know if something like this exists in ROS.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-19**:
I concur. I don't know of any code that does this.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
There is lot of algorithms which deal about that specific issue, so I'm surprise that anybody tried to implement one of this algorithms

**Comment by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on 2014-07-27**:
is there a ROS package that supports autonomous map building?  for example, we can just place the robot in a room and it begins to build the map by itself vs. teleop control.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-07-29**:
Re-exploring a known area was my initial use case for http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration. You can use the client tool to set an exploration boundary in rviz. It can also be used to explore an unknown area with gmapping.

**Comment by [herodotus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5890/herodotus/) on 2014-09-16**:
Paul,I find your package is a good job.I'm a newer to ROS and when I use your package I have some trouble that I can't build it.when I use the command catkin_make in the root of my own workspace there are some errors.It says "Could not find a configuration file for package costmap_2d and move_base_m

**Comment by [herodotus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5890/herodotus/) on 2014-09-16**:
so can you tell me how to solve the question or how you build this package?Thank you.

**Comment by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on 2015-02-22**:
So was anyone able to figure out how to cover the complete map and not just part of the map as done in exploration?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-02-22**:
Please ask a new question instead of resurrecting a ~5 month old one. If you send frontier_exploration a goal with an empty polygon, it should perform an unbounded search.

**Comment by [gautam2410](https://answers.ros.org/users/5500/gautam2410/) on 2015-03-06**:
The same question has been asked [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/203867/how-to-instruct-a-robot-to-cover-the-whole-mapped-2d-area/) so I am not posting a new question. Can you please explain how to give the goal with an empty polygon? By unbounded search do you mean the total map coverage?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The heatmap package (http://wiki.ros.org/heatmap) says it does coverage path planning as part of its functionality. The source code is here and looks maintained: https://github.com/eybee/heatmap/tree/jade-devel

The heatmap package itself uses the coverage path planner from the Auburn Autonomous Lawnmower stack (https://github.com/Auburn-Automow/au_automow_common), which looks out of date.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) on 2016-07-14**:
Hi there. Do you know why the heatmap uses wifi? Is it possible for me to get coverage by just using the automow?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-07-14**:
Because it's a "ROS package for automated creation of visual WiFi heatmaps." I suspect that you would have to tinker with the source code to only use the coverage functionality.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-07-14**:
Or maybe not. See what happens if you run this launch file without the wi-fi stuff: [heatmap_sim.launch](https://github.com/eybee/heatmap/blob/jade-devel/launch/heatmap_sim.launch)

**Comment by [jjbecomespheh](https://answers.ros.org/users/55607/jjbecomespheh/) on 2020-08-12**:
Yeap it works but unfortunately it is only used to generate coverage way points of a geometry polygon drawn by using publish_point in rviz. It does not generate coverage path for your input map.